# Ugly output when running NPM commands from Windows

Tags: windows, node.js, console, npm

I have manually installed "node.exe" (0.10.36 x64) & NPM Zip (1.4.12) under Windows 7.

When I run a NPM command (from cmd, powershell or Eclipse TCF terminals), it prints a lot of a new line with single character from this list: -\|/.
However, it doesn't with Eclipse console.

It uselessly fills the console and makes difficult to see messages, especially when running some infinite running command like "karma start".

Is there any way to remove/fix these ugly output characters ?

Comment: Which console are you using? powershell? cmd? though i'm not having the same issue in either, just thought it could be useful information for someone else.

Comment: I have encountered same issue using cmd, powershell and Eclipse TCF terminals. However Eclipse standard console (using run external tools) seems ok (except for ANSI Escape)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an issue of "1.4.12" and "1.4.13" versions. Switch back to 1.4.10 (1.4.11 doesn't work at all on my computer) has solved the issue.

Another solution can be to upgrade to newer versions of npm simply running `npm install npm --global`. If want to easy switch NPM versions, just copy "npm.cmd" and "node_modules/npm" to another directory. Then *from this directory*, run `npm install npm`. Finally, update your PATH to take this directory in priority (or remove the old npm versions).

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue on Win 10. I was previously using v0.12.7 (I did not know why I used a so "old" version) then installed v4.2.2 which makes ugly output.

To solve this problem, I uninstalled v4.2.2 from Control Panel, removed `npm` and `npm_cache` folder from `%APPDATA%`, and finally removed all paths related to Node and npm from PATH environment variable.

Hope this could help someone.